# Count with IF Condition

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table with following structure:

```
User  Condition  Date

A        New          2019-01-01

B       New           2019-01-01

B       Old            2019-02-01

C       New          2019-01-01
```

I want to calculate the number of 'New' users. I've tried to use this formula:

```
If ATTR([Condition])="New" then COUNT([User]) END
```

Bu the calculation isn't going through. I'm only getting null values. Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the whole formula in count.

```
count(if [condition]='New' then [user] end)
```

Comment: Right, and I don't think you need the ATTR. As @Bernardo pointed out, it is better/required to do aggregations outside of IF statements and not within.

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent solution is `sum(int(condition = ‘New’))` Int() converts True to 1 and False to 0